How to annotate plain javascript "overloads" to avoid errors in calls and have correct type in the function?
I have JavaScript type checking enabled in my project with the following jsconfig.json settings:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "checkJs": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "module": "NodeNext"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*",
        "**/purest/build/*"
    ]
}

I often have "overloads" that allow multiple types, but either execute slightly differently based on the type, or convert to a uniform type.
Example 1 - conversion to uniform value:
class AccountInfo {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {string} accountName 
     */
    constructor(accountName, someFlag) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.someFlag = someFlag;
    }
}
/**
 * 
 * @param {AccountInfo[]|string[]|string} accountNames
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function createAccounts(accountNames) {
    if(typeof accountNames == "string") {
        accountNames = [accountNames];
    }
    for(let i=0; i<accountNames.length; ++i) {
        // this prevents an error on assignment
        //     Argument of type 'string | AccountInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
        //     Type 'AccountInfo' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
        // if accountNames[i] the typeof does not translate to it correctly
        const acc = accountNames[i];
        if(typeof acc == "string") {
            accountNames[i] = new AccountInfo(acc, false);
        }
    }
    // perform some operation here where I can know accountNames are always array of account info
    /**
     *
     * @param {AccountInfo} accountInfo
     */
    function doWithAccountInfo(accountInfo) {
        // do something with account info
    }
    for(const acc of accountNames) {
        // this is underlined because the type checker does not know that acc is always AccountInfo
        //     Argument of type 'string | AccountInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AccountInfo'.
        //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AccountInfo'.ts(2345)
        doWithAccountInfo(acc);
    }
    return true;
}

I put the errors I see in the comments. Ideally, I would like to do something like:
/** @type {AccountInfo[]} **/
accountNames;

This should coerce the type to the correct one, or at least it would be convenient, but it does not work - it has no effect on the variable.
I can fix this bu assigning accountNames to a different variable, but I don't really want to do runtime changes just to make type system happy.
How to you solve this to get benefits of type checking while keeping the benefits of weak typing?

You could cast from the caller end -> doWithAccountInfo(/** @type {AccountInfo} */ (acc));  Note the extra brackets, it won't work without them.

You can explicitly cast accountNames to AccountInfo[]
function createAccounts(accountNames) {
  if (typeof accountNames == "string") {
    ...
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < accountNames.length; ++i) {
    ...
  }
  //  cast accountNames to AccountInfo[]
  accountNames = /**@type {AccountInfo[]}*/(accountNames)
  // perform some operation here where I can know accountNames are always array of account info
  ...
  for (const acc of accountNames) {
    ...
  }
  return true;
}

